# DropdownListFor on Change updates and posts parent object

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Man..and I thought my project would be nice and easy....

Here's my problem:

I'm making a checklist for a project manager using MVC 4, and I have an Editor Template for each Task Item. Within each Task Item, I have a DropDownListFor which the user can use to select the task state ('complete', 'inprogress', etc.)

When the user changes the task state, The script goes and adds a completion date (if changed to completed state). I also want it to update and save the task changes in the database by using my HttpPost method, "UpdateTaskState".

As a side question, is this the correct and proper way to acheive my goal? I'd love to have it so that I don't need to refresh the tasks view every time a change is made too..

My task editor template:

```
@model Models.task

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.task_id, new { @id = "taskID" })
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.task_name)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.task_desc)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.user_completed,new {@id = "UserCompleted" })
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.completion_date, new { @id = "CompletionDate" })

<table style="width:80%">
    <tr style="width:60%">
        <th colspan="3">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.task_name)</th>
        <th align="left">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.task_state_id,
    new SelectList((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["TaskStates"], "task_state_id", "state"),
             new { @Id = "ddlState" })
    </th>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.notes, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.notes, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </td>    
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.task_desc)</td>
        <td>@Html.Label("Completed by ")@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.user_completed)@Html.Label(", ")@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.completion_date)</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

My main view with script:

```
@model NSCEngineering.Models.NRIAndCategoriesViewModel
@{ ViewBag.Title = "Details";}

<h2>Details</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <hr />
    @Html.HiddenFor(item => Model.TaskStates)
    @Html.HiddenFor(item => Model.id, new{ @id ="NriID" })
    <div class="NRISummary">
    @Html.LabelFor(item => Model.Summary )
    @Html.DisplayFor(item => Model.Summary, "_nri")
        </div>
    <hr />
    <div class="tasks">  
    @Html.LabelFor(item => Model.Tasks )
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Tasks.Count(); i++ )
        {
            @Html.EditorFor(item => Model.Tasks[i], "_task", new{@id = "taskItem"})
        }
        </div>
    </div>
}

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>

@section Scripts{

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(this.document).ready(function () {
    $('#ddlState').change(function () //wire up on change event of the 'country' dropdownlist
    {
        var selection = $('#ddlState').val(); //get the selection made in the dropdownlist
        if (selection == '4') {
            $('#CompletionDate').val('@DateTime.Now.Date');
        }
        var completion = $('#CompletionDate').val();
        alert(completion);
        alert($('#taskID').val());
        var url = '@Url.Action("UpdateTaskState", "nris")';
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: $('#taskItem').serializeArray(),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (e) {
                $("#message").html("Success");
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                // Show the error
                $('#message').html(xhr.responseText);
            }
        })

    })
});
```

}

**UPDATE1**

```
@model NSCEngineering.Models.NRIAndCategoriesViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            <p>
                @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    @Html.LabelFor(item => Model.nriSummary)
    @Html.DisplayFor(item => Model.nriSummary, "_nri")  //just displays project summary details
    <div class="form-group">        
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Categories.Count; i++)
        {
            <div style="border:solid ; border-width:1px">
               <table class="category" style="width:100%">
                   <thead style="font-size:large ; background-color:black">
                      @Html.DisplayFor(c => c.Categories[i].category_name)
                   </thead>
                   <tbody>
                       <tr>
                           @renderTasksControl(Model.Categories[i].tasks, Model.StateList)
                       </tr>                           
                       @for (int k = 0; k < Model.Categories[i].Subcategories.Count; k++)
                       {
                           <tr>
                               <td>
                                   <table>
                                       <thead style="font-size:larger">
                                           @Html.DisplayFor(c => c.Categories[i].Subcategories[k].category_name)
                                           @renderCategoryPercentage(Model.Categories[i].Subcategories[k].tasks)
                                       </thead>
                                       <tbody>
                                           @renderTasksControl(Model.Categories[i].Subcategories[k].tasks, Model.StateList)
                                       </tbody>
                                   </table>
                               </td>
                            </tr>                           
                       }
                   </tbody>
               </table>
                </div>
        }
        </div>
}


@helper renderTasksControl(IList<NSCEngineering.Models.task> TaskList, SelectList states) {
    for (int i = 0; i < TaskList.Count; i++) { 
    <div class="task">
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => TaskList[i].task_name)   
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => TaskList[i].task_state_id, states, new { @class = "ddlState" })
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => TaskList[i].task_id)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => TaskList[i].nri_id)
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => TaskList[i].completion_date, new { @class = "date" })
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => TaskList[i].category_id)

                @*@Html.EditorFor(model => Task.notes)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Task.notes, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })*@
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => TaskList[i].task_desc)
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => TaskList[i].user_completed)

</div>
}
}

@helper renderCategoryPercentage(IList<NSCEngineering.Models.task> taskList) { 
   int sum = 0;
   int total = 0;
   var percentage = "";
     foreach (NSCEngineering.Models.task task in taskList)
    {
        if (task.task_state_id != -1) { 
             sum += task.task_state_id;
        }
         total += 3;         
    }
     if (total != 0){
         var ratio = ((double)sum / total);
         percentage = string.Format("{0:0.0%}", ratio);
         }
     else { 
         percentage = "Invalid Value";
     }
    <text> @sum + @total </text> 
    <br />
    @percentage
};  

@section Scripts{

<script type="text/javascript">
 //this is me trying to get the completiondate to programatically update
    $(this.document).ready(function () {
        $('.ddlState').change(function () {
            if ($('.ddlState').val() == 3) {
                date = '@DateTime.Now.Date';
                var task = $(this).closest('.task');
                var completionDate = task.children('.date');
                task.children($('.date')).text(date);
                alert(date);
                alert(task.children($('.date')).text());
            }
            else {
                $('.completion_date').val(null);
            }
        //    location.reload(true);
        })
    });
</script>
}

public partial class category
{
    public category()
    {
        tasks = new List<task>();
        Subcategories = new List<category>();
    }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public byte category_id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string category_name { get; set; }
    public byte? parent_category_id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("parent_category_id")]
    public category ParentCategory { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("ParentCategory")]
    public virtual IList<category> Subcategories { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<task> tasks { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Lots of issues here. First replace `@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Tasks.Count(); i++ ) { @Html.EditorFor(item => Model.Tasks[i], "_task", new{@id = "taskItem"})}` with `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Tasks)` (your EditorTemplate should be named Task.cshtml). Why set the date in javascript? - it would be better to set this in the controller when you post back (ditto for the user). Why not just post the whole form back at once using a normal submit?

Comment: yeah. I was debating if i should set the date in the postback or not.  I think the bigger issue i have is to get the dropdownlist to correctly trigger the postback.  I feel like i'm just missing something simple.

Comment: @StephenMuecke and to answer you question about posting back the whole form, it didnt make sense for me to post the whole list of tasks and update it all every time one is changed.. just seemed unnecessary.  Though I trust your judgement more than mine.

Comment: @StephenMuecke so i got it to postback and call the method.  But it only works for the first task.  If i move the script to the editor template,  i cant get it working anymore.  I put the dropdownlistfor as a class instead and tried to pull the data, but it pulls the fields from the first task, regardless of which dropdownlist was changed.  Any ideas?

Comment: Some issues to consider. 1. Your creating invalid html with duplicate id attributes (not to mention other semantically incorrect html like `th` elements in `tbody`). 2. Your setting the `CompletionDate` to the DateTime when the user loads the page, not when the user saves the task. 3. Your including unnecessary hidden elements and posting them back degrading performance. 4. Your creating a new `SelectList` for each row (rather than creating it once on the server and using it in each row).

Comment: 5. Setting `new{@id = "taskItem"}` in the `EditorFor` does NOT set an id attribute so `data: $('#taskItem').serializeArray(),` does nothing There is not element with `id="taskitem"` and if it did work, every row would have `id="taskitem"` so the whole form would have posted back with each dropdown change anyway!). 6. `$('#CompletionDate').val('@DateTime.Now.Date');` changes only the value in the first row.

Comment: Just use a view model to represent what you want to display and either post the back the whole form or properly construct the data to post back just the `task_id`,` task_state_id`, and `notes` properties for each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by creating a view model that represents what you want to display/edit and avoid sending and receiving unnecessary data across the wire

View models

```
public class TaskViewModel
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int State { get; set; }
  public string Description { get; set; }
  public string Notes { get; set; }
}

public class NRIAndCategoriesViewModel
{
  public List<TaskViewModel> Tasks { get; set; }
  public SelectList StateList { get; set; }
  // other properties of the model to display in the main view
}
```

In your GET method, initialize an instance of `NRIAndCategoriesViewModel`, map the properties of the tasks to the collection of `TaskViewModel` and assign the `StateList` (create the `SelectList` once rather that passing a collection via `ViewData` and constructing the `SelectList` for each task).

View

```
@model NSCEngineering.Models.NRIAndCategoriesViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  ...
  for (int i = 0; i < Model.Tasks.Count; i++)
  {
    <div class="task">
      @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Tasks[i].ID, new { @class = "id" })
      @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Tasks[i].Name)
      @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Tasks[i].State, Model.StateList, new { @class = "state" })
      @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Tasks[i].Notes, new { @class = "notes" })
      @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Tasks[i].Description)
    </div>
  }
  <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

Note you could use an `EditorTemplate` for `TaskViewModel` but the correct use is

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Tasks)
```

Do not use it inside a for loop or specify the templates name (doing it as you have is overriding the default behavior and you end up with duplicate `name` and `id` attributes)

This will submit the form back to your controller

```
public ActionResult UpdateTaskState(NRIAndCategoriesViewModel viewModel)
```

so you can (1) check for validation errors and return the view if necessary, (2) get the data model from the database, (3) loop each `TaskViewModel` in `viewModel.Tasks` and update the corresponding properties in the data model including the current date and userID, (4) save the data model, and finally (5) redirect to the `Index` view.

You seem to be overly concerned about this is making too many database calls. If your using EF, then only the tasks that have been modified will be saved (not all of them, so the net result is the same - in fact, its worse if the user selects the wrong `State` and then corrects it since extra calls are being made). And its somewhat ironic since sending and posting a whole lot of useless data as your doing is having a far worse affect than the database call. However if you do want to post back only one task at a time (and as a consequence lose benefits such as client side unobtrusive validation) then you could use the following script

```
var url = '@Url.Action("UpdateTaskState", "nris")';
$('.State').change(function() {
  var state = $(this).val();
  var task = $(this).closest('.task');
  var id = task.children('.id').val();     
  var notes = task.children('.notes').val();
  $.post(url, {ID: id, State: state, Notes: notes }, function(response) {
    // do something with the response
  });
});
```

and then change the controller to

```
public ActionResult UpdateTaskState(TaskViewModel viewModel)
```

Note if your rendering the controls in a table row, you will need to modify the selectors to suit your table layout

But consider this from the user perspective. A user would not expect that the data would be saved just by selecting an item from a drop down list. If the users selects an item from the drop down list and then modifies the `Notes`, the notes will never be saved and the user will be none the wiser. Its poor UI design and all very confusing! Stick with the standard `submit` which allows the user to modify the data, check it, and make a conscious decision to then save it.

Comment: Awesome!! forever grateful!  Tweaking it a bit but this works perferctly so far!

Comment: Can I ask what happens if i use the Editor Template in a for loop?  The reason I'm asking is that I want to group and organize the tasks in a hierarchical grouping,  so instead of reiterating the same task controls many times, it'd make sense to make a template.  **Edit:** Actually, I can probably just use an HTML Helper for that.

Comment: No problem using an `EditorTemplate` for a collection, but to render all the tasks correctly, use `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Tasks)`. This will render all the tasks and name them correctly with indexers. If `Tasks` contains another collection, then in `Tasks.cshtml` use `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.OtherCollection)`. If you use loop and then call the editor passing the name, it will not name the controls correctly (no indexers so no binding!). Just experiment with a simple class containing a collection to see the differences in the html generated.

Comment: I'm having trouble getting the postback to return the ViewModel using jQuery. All the fields are returning null.

Comment: Why are you doing this anyway (its actually worse than posting back the whole form - read my comments and the answer in detail)? What is the script you using to post back and what is the signature of the method your posting back to?

Comment: sorry i should have elaborated. at first i was trying to post back the whole form (the whole NRIAndCategoriesViewModel).  I'm also separately trying to get a script to enter in the current date into the completion_date field when the state is set to 'completed'

Comment: Without seeing your revised code I cant tell what you might have done wrong. I can only suggest you study the html your generating. Your inputs names must match the models property names and for collections they must include indexers. For example `<input type="hidden" name="Tasks[0].ID" value="1" />` will bind the value of `1` to property `ID` of the first `TaskViewModel` in `model.Tasks`

Comment: and i'm using <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" /> to post back the viewmodel

Comment: figured it out. I ended up using an EditorFor for each task to make sure that the indexing is done correctly. The EditorFor doesn't postback, and I can use the save button and return the viewmodel.  Thank you again greatly for all your help!